# Navigate from an Android.App.Activity/Android.App.Fragment to Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-fragmentactivity

Given an `Android.App.Activity` or an `Android.App.Activity`, how can I navigate to a `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity`?

---

#### Context

I have an application where I was asked to add a QrCode scanner. I'm using the ZXing libraries and, to use their `MobileBarcodeScanner` I need the Activity to be a `FragmentActivity`, otherwise I'll get a `System.MissingMethodException`:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException:
    Method 'Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission' not found.
```

But since this wasn't a requirement at the beggining of the project, I went and worked with `Android.App.Activity` and `Android.App.Fragment` to the point where I actually use an extended version of it to include some methods and properties I needed.

Since the project become rather big and complex -- and I relied too much on those types -- it's kinda difficult to swap the `Android.App.*` to the `Android.Suppor.V4.App.*` without having some bugs here and there.

Is there any solution for this case, or should I start on rebuilding the project from scratch?

Comment: support fragments should never be used mixed with fragments. I even not sure that you can use them together. But you defintely should not.

Comment: Please refer to [Migrating to AppcompatActivity](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Migrating-to-the-AppCompat-Library). And please offer the codes of your Activity, if you need help specifically.